# Retrieving network username from Windows network 

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis-7, windows-authentication

Please forgive my naivety on this post as I am used to developing in a LAMP environment and not a Microsoft .NET environment, so I am a bit out of my comfort zone here.

I am developing a single page Intranet on a Windows Network.  Users are authenticated against an active directory windows 2008 server.  I wish my Intranet page to seamlessly gather the authenticated user's network username without the need to enter credentials a second time.  I have been able to get the username, but only after the browser has forced a second log in.

I am running IIS 7 and have configured it so that:

```
Anonymous User is disabled
Integrated Windows Authentication is enabled
```

My web.config file contains the following text:

```
<identity impersonate="false"/>
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

My C# code is as follows:

```
public partial class AuthUser : System.Web.UI.Page {

  protected void Page_Init( object sender, EventArgs e ) {

    Response.Write(User.Identity.Name);

  } 
}
```

So my question is:

How do I emplement a seamless authentication that gathers the logged in users Network Username without a second authentication?

Comment: I recall something about having the Identity Framework for this. Sorry not having more info.

Comment: From my experience there is no easy way to do it, if you're using IE then adding your web app to the trusted sites and lowering the security for trusted sites (can be done by group policy) but if anyone is using FF/Chrome/Opera then they need to give their windows credentials a second time

Comment: Firefox can be configured to use GSSAPI or SSPI in order to support SSO via the `WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate` header. For a complete answer, more information about the browser and network setup may be required.

Comment: All of our users (fortunately in this case) only have the option of using IE.  I have added the IP address of the Intranet Server to the trusted sites for local intranets on my browser and this stopped the second auth box popping up.  If I can add this as a group policy for the whole network, this should be sufficent to get my project running.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic logon with Active Directory is only possible in IE, with adding the site into Trusted Sites(which you did), and also changing the setting in IE >> Internet options >> (select Trusted Sites) >> Custom Level:

```
User Authentication >> Logon >> Automatic logon with current user name and password.
```